# Reading and printing out Unicode and UTF-8 encodings in C

Tags: c, windows, unicode, character-encoding, console

I'm using Windows XP.
I want to read from files in ASCII, UTF-8 and Unicode encodings and print out strings on stdout.
I was trying to use functions from wchar.h like **fgetwc()/fputwc()** and **fgetws()/fputws**(), they work on ASCII but not when a file is in UTF-8 or Unicode. Doesn't print out language specific characters and when a file is in Unicode it doesn't print out anything but the box and first letter.
Is there any way of making a program in pure C that will read files, compare strings and print them out correctly on stdout regardless of the encoding of the files fed to the program?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but what does “print them correctly” mean to you?

Comment: Well what way is it than? By that i mean for non ASCII letters, like for example ščćđž, to be read from the files compared and printed on stdout.

Comment: “Unicode” is not an encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Windows, the key is that you want to write your strings out using the [`WriteConsoleW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, having first assembled the sequence of UTF-16 characters that you want to write out. (You probably should only write a few kilobytes of characters at a time.) Use `GetStdHandle` to obtain the console handle, of course.

Harder is determining the encoding of a file. Luckily, you don't need to distinguish between ASCII and UTF-8 as the latter is a strict superset of the former. But for *any* other single-byte encoding, you need to guess. Some UTF-8 files, more likely so on Windows than elsewhere, have a UTF-8 encoded byte-order mark at the beginning of the file; that's nasty as BOMs are not really supposed to be used with UTF-8, but a strong indicator if present. (Spotting UTF-16 is easier, as it should either have a byte-order mark, or you can guess it from the presence of NUL (0) bytes.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little piece of code I used to print various characters outside of the ASCII subset of Unicode (contains workarounds for what seems to be a bug in the Open Watcom compiler's implementation of printf()):

```
// Compile with Open Watcom C/C++ 1.9: wcl386 cons-utf8.c

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

// Workarounds for printf() not printing multi-byte (UTF-8) strings
// with Open Watcom C/C++ 1.7-1.9.
// 0 - no workaround for printf()
// 1 - setbuf(stdout, NULL) before printf()
// 2 - fflush(stdout) after printf()
// 3 - WriteConsole() instead of printf()
#define PRINT_WORKAROUND 03

int main(void)
{
  DWORD err, i, j;
  // Code point ranges of characters to print
  static const DWORD ranges[][2] =
  {
    { 0x0A0, 0x0FF }, // Latin chars with diacritic marks + some others
    { 0x391, 0x3CE }, // Greek chars
    { 0x410, 0x44F }  // Cyrillic chars
  };

#if PRINT_WORKAROUND == 1
  setbuf(stdout, NULL);
#endif

  if (!SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8))
  {
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8) failed with error 0x%X\n", err);
    goto Exit;
  }

  printf("Workaround: %d\n", PRINT_WORKAROUND);

  for (j = 0; j < sizeof(ranges) / sizeof(ranges[0]); j++)
  {
    for (i = ranges[j][0]; i <= ranges[j][1]; i++)
    {
      char str[8];
      int sz;
      wchar_t wstr[2];
      wstr[0] = i;
      wstr[1] = 0;

      sz = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,
                               0,
                               wstr,
                               -1,
                               str,
                               sizeof(str),
                               NULL,
                               NULL);
      if (sz <= 0)
      {
        err = GetLastError();
        printf("WideCharToMultiByte() failed with error 0x%X\n", err);
        goto Exit;
      }

#if PRINT_WORKAROUND < 3
      printf("%s", str);
#if PRINT_WORKAROUND == 2
      fflush(stdout);
#endif
#else
      WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                   str,
                   sz - 1,
                   &err,
                   NULL);
#endif
    }

    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");

Exit:

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\>cons-utf8.exe

Workaround: 3
 ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡ΢ΣΤΥΦΧΨΩΪΫάέήίΰαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφχψωϊϋόύώ
АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя
```

I didn't find a way to print UTF-16 code points directly to the console in Windows XP that would work the same as above.

Comment: Very nice coding, thanks. It gave me lot's of insides of Windows specific programming.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way of making a program in pure C that will read files, compare strings and print them out correctly on stdout regardless of the encoding of the files fed to the program?

No, the program has obviously to told the encoding of the files too. Internally, you can choose to represent the data of the files with multibyte strings in UTF-8 or with wide strings.

Comment: @Billy Yes, Windows uses UTF-16 for wide strings/characters too. I never said it wasn't "valid" (whatever that means).

Comment: Your text says "multibyte strings in UTF-8 or with wide strings" -- UTF-16 is both "multibyte" in the same way UTF-8 is, yet it is also wider than a `char`. (Truly "wide" strings use UTF-32/UCS-4)

Comment: @Billy "multibyte character" and "wide character" have a precisely defined meaning (see 3.7.2 and 3.7.3 in C99), and it's that meaning I'm referring to.

Comment: Multibyte character and wide character do have defined meaning according to C. They have no meaning with respect to Unicode.

Comment: It's possible to establish heuristics for guessing encodings, but really difficult to get perfect.